# box authentication URL for mobiles

Tags: box-api

I haven't got answer so I am updating this question

as per the reply from Mr. Seanrose the link should adjust on the mobile vieport but it doesnt, so is there any other link I should use for authantication on the mobile ?

I am developing the HTML5/javascript based mobile application for box. for getting the auth code I use following url 
https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&state=authenticated'

but this is non mobile url hence the page is getting displayed very small. is there mobile specific URL for authentication ?

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

When you visit that page from a mobile device, it should detect viewport dimensions and adjust to a mobile-friendly page, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply!
unfortunately it doesn't adjust to the mobile friendly page. I am using the BlackBerry 10 device. though I am not sure of this but is there any setting on device would help ?

Comment: Hello Seanrose,

As I mentioned, the page doesnt adjust to the mobile viewport, is there mobile specific page can be used to overcome this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: We recently adjusted the page to recognize Blackberry mobile devices, can you verify that it is fixed?